# Yahtzee Game Main Method

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I seem to be having some issues running my Yahtzee game in Java. I keep getting a "Main method not found" error in my code, even though I specify it earlier in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class NathanMassey_221_Midterm {

int faceValue;
public void roll(){
    faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
}

public int getValue(){
    return faceValue;   
}

public String toString(){
    return Integer.toString(faceValue);
}
}

class Yahtzee {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        introduction();
        boolean runAgain = true;
        while (runAgain){
            boolean rolledYahtzee = false;
            int numRolls = 0;
            NathanMassey_221_Midterm [] dieArray = dieArray(keyboard);
            while(!rolledYahtzee){
                dieArray = rollDice (dieArray);
                numRolls++;
                printDots(numRolls);
                rolledYahtzee = checkForYahtzee(dieArray, numRolls);
            }
            printResults (numRolls, dieArray);
            runAgain = runAgain(keyboard);
        }
}

public static void introduction(){
    System.out.println("This program will");
}


public static NathanMassey_221_Midterm [] dieArray(Scanner keyboard){
    int numDice = getInt(keyboard, "How many dice do you want to throw? ");
    while (numDice <= 0){
        System.out.println("Sorry, you must enter a positive number.");
        numDice = getInt(keyboard, "How many dice do you want to throw? ");
    }
    NathanMassey_221_Midterm [] dieArray = new NathanMassey_221_Midterm [numDice];
    return dieArray;
}

public static int getInt (Scanner keyboard, String prompt){
    System.out.print(prompt);
    while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()){
        keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Sorry, you must enter an integer.");
        System.out.print(prompt);
    }
    return keyboard.nextInt();
}

public static NathanMassey_221_Midterm [] rollDice(NathanMassey_221_Midterm [] dieArray){
    for (int i = 0; i < dieArray.length; i++){
        dieArray[i] = new NathanMassey_221_Midterm ();
        dieArray[i].roll();
        dieArray[i].faceValue = dieArray[i].getValue();
    }
    return dieArray;
}

public static void printDots(int numRolls){
    System.out.print(".");
    if ((numRolls%50) == 0){
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static boolean checkForYahtzee(NathanMassey_221_Midterm[] dieArray, int numRolls) {
    for(int i = 0; i < dieArray.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < dieArray.length; j++) {
            if(dieArray[i].getValue() != dieArray[j].getValue()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void printResults (int numRolls, NathanMassey_221_Midterm[] dieArray){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Yahtzee!!");
    System.out.print("After " + numRolls + " rolls, I finally rolled ");
    System.out.println(dieArray.length + " " + dieArray[0].getValue() + "'s");
    System.out.println();   
}

public static boolean runAgain (Scanner keyboard){
    System.out.print("Do you want to run another experiment? (y|n)):    ");
    String answer = keyboard.next().trim().toLowerCase();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    return (answer.charAt(0) == 'y');
}
}
```

Comment: Put your different classes into their own files as there's no need to squeeze a bunch of classes in one file, at least not for the code you're creating.

Comment: You want your Yahtzee class public.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried separating out the classes, for instance having a main class. It's not very good practice shoving everything into one file also I do not believe java likes having a main class within another class this is the immediate issue. Also are you using an IDE or some kind of build utility? and which specific IDE or build utility? if you do want everything in one class get rid of the class header before the main method

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to access the main method of the public class NathanMassey_221_Midterm, which does not exist. If you are working in Eclipse, for example, you will have to create the Launch Configuration yourself and specify Yahtzee as the main class (iirc, per default, clicking "run" will try to run the main method of the public class).

Comment: Can you specify further? I'm kind of new to Java so any examples of what I should would be appreciated. I'm also using Netbeans.

Comment: Sorry, never used Netbeans. I would suggest following the suggestings already given, separating your classes into two files, making both classes public, which should probably make things a lot easier.